# Display 0 when no data in dates in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

A lot of people have problems with displaying null values in dates in graphs in Tableau. Tableau automatically joins values that actually exist for specific dates and neglects missing data. I've solved this problem converting my datetime date to a date itself (makedate). Then I right-clicked on the date axis and clicked Format. Clicked "Pane", Special Values -> Text: 0, Marks: Show at Default Value. Next I clicked on Date pane in Columns and made it discrete. This unblocked the possibility to Show Missing Values. I right-clicked on Date axis and chose this option. I clicked on Nulls on the Graph and chose to show them at default values. Finally, I converted Date pane back to Continuous.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I suggest to reform this in a question+ answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

You could try this formula using `IFNULL` function

```
IFNULL(MONTH([DATE]),0)
```

Another function you can use is ZN() instead of IFNULL() which does the same thing as above, except that the default value of zero is baked into the function.

I'm not sure that a formula that returns zero for a date makes sense in most applications though. Sometimes it is better to leave the nulls and then decide how to visualize them. Otherwise, you are masking missing information and replacing it with possibly misleading information.

[More info here](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/replacing-null-literalsclass)